# how to return a List of active objects in Android IPC

Tags: android, ipc, generic-list, aidl

Trying to remote some interfaces from an Android service app to another client app, and using the AIDL approach..
So I have an interface *IJobController* in IJobController.aidl:
    import com.example.jobs.api.IJobExecutionContext;

```
interface IJobController {
    List<IJobExecutionContext> getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
    ...
}
```

where IJobExecutionContext is defined in its own AIDL:

```
interface IJobExecutionContext {    
  Bundle getJobResult();
  ...
  long getJobStartTime();
  long getJobEndTime();
  long getJobRunTime();
}
```

When those definitions are compiled in the *gen* folder, I get errors like these in the generated IJobController.java file:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<IBinder> to List<IJobExecutionContext>  
The method writeBinderList(List<IBinder>) in the type Parcel is not applicable for the arguments (List<IJobExecutionContext>)
```

From what I understand such interfaces can be used in a List (or Map) along with primitive types, Parcelable, etc.
In another method where I return just an AIDL interface, everything is ok, but it seems that in the list container it is not.

Do I need to just return a raw List, or a list of an implementation of the IJobExecutionContext which is also *Parcelable*?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Binder knows nothing about your interface `IJobExecutionContext`, it does not know how to deal with it. Binder knows how to marshal and unmarshal only primitive types. In other cases, you need to explain it how to perform these operations implementing Parcelable interface. Thus, to my knowledge, you cannot work with the interfaces in AIDL files. You need to substitute `IJobExecutionContext` with the class that implements this interface. Additionally, this class must also implement `Parcelable` interface.